# Why isn't a quark-antiquark loop included in the photon self-energy corrections?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, photons, standard-model, estimation, self-energy

In QED, the Lagrangian has a term $\bar{\psi}A^\mu\psi$, which gives a correction to the photon propagator, where the loop is made of a pair electron-positron, with the 1st order diagram:

[image: electron loop]

In the Standard Model, there are also couplings such as $\bar{u}A^\mu u$ and $\bar{d}A^\mu d$, which would give rise to a similar correction (changing mass and dividing the coupling by 3). but I have never seen this discussion in a QFT textbook. Isn't this correction important? Wouldn't it change how we measure the vacuum polarization? The electron mass is $\sim0.51$MeV while the up quark mass is $\sim2.2$MeV, so it isn't heavy enough to be ignored.

One reason I thought could explain this is that the range of electromagnetic interactions is much larger than that of the strong force, so the quark-antiquark pair would hadronize before they could annihilate, but I'm not completely convinced this is true. Can anybody shed a light on this?

Answer (score 2):

QED is the theory of electrons and photons only. When extended to the Standard Model quark loops are included.

Comment: Yes, but this is not what most textbooks say. Perhaps I wasn't clear: I ask if the vacuum polarization usually computed in textbooks is accurate with real life measurements of vacuum polarization or there is some term missing due to a quark-antiquark loop

Comment: Quark loops should indeed be included, but don't expect accurate answers until you reach the GeV range.  Quarks are not free particles, and the pion mass exceeds 100 MeV, so the production threshold is definitely not 4.4 GeV.

Comment: @BertBarrois virtual particles don’t need to be on shell, so production threshold doesn’t apply inside a virtual particle loop. However, heavier particles indeed contribute less to polarization (see my answer).

Comment: Don't forget the first lesson of dispersion relationships.  The loop does not contribute to the imaginary part of the propagator below the physical production threshold.

Answer (score 2):

The polarized vacuum is effectively described by the Euler-Heisenberg lagrangian. The nonlinear term is proportional to the inverse of the virtual particle mass, so lighter particles like electrons contribute the most.